# what's happen earlier in Python during creating a variable?

Tags: python, object, variables

Does the interpretator make a name or object?
for example:
VAR = 100
Initially, interpreter makes a name VAR and assigns to VAR an object with the value 100 or interpreter creates an object with the value 100 and further creates a name VAR and assign to it an object ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "name" or "object". Could you clarify what your source of confusion is?

Comment: Why do you ask? I can't think of any situation where there'd be any difference in behaviour for a basic assignment like this.

Comment: var = 1
def f():
    var = var + 1
if a var is created earlier I can understand a logic based on legb rule, else I can't

Comment: @vipnoob Well that's a totally different situation, cause then scope is a factor. See [UnboundLocalError on local variable when reassigned after first use](/q/370357/4518341)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It creates a new object, but according to [this documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/long.html#c.PyLong_FromLong), there are ready to use objects that have already been created for all integers between `-5` and `256`, so in your example Python already has an integer object created for `100` that will be referenced instead of creating a brand new object.

To answer your next question, if `var=257` Python will still create an object. What gets created first? Well, there is a module called `dis` that lets us disassemble any Python code to the bytecode that gets generated. If we do

```
dis.dis('var = 257')
```

Then we get

```
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (257)
              2 STORE_NAME               0 (var)
              4 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
              6 RETURN_VALUE
```

You can see what each of the bytecode instructions do [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#bytecodes).

The bytecode instruction for [STORE_NAME](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#opcode-STORE_NAME) says (TOS stands for top of stack):

> STORE_NAME(namei)
>
> Implements name = TOS. namei is the index of name in
> the attribute co_names of the [code object](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/datamodel.html#index-55).

No further information is shared if the name is added to `co_names` (code object names) before the PyLongObject [(cPython's int object)](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/long.html#c.PyLongObject) is created. Often times the [compile.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/65e7c1f90e9136fc61f4af029b065d9f6c5664c3/Python/compile.c#L6207) file of cPython gives good insights into how bytecode operations work under the hood, but I wasn't able to find an exact answer to your question in the source code. I would imagine that the `PyLongObject` is created first and then added to `co_names` as otherwise you would have to add the name and set it to null and then go back and change it after you have created the `PyLongObject`, which is just messier and slower.

Comment: okey if var = 257, what will be created first ?